# Кто может помочь с заданием по обработке изображения?

Tags: python, изображения, jupyter-notebook, double, wavelet

Необходимо помочь с 2 заданиями по обработке изображения, а именно сжатие изображения с помощью двумерного вейвлет преобразования (DWT) и использование дескриптора SIFT. За вознаграждение. Коды на Jupyter, как и изображения скину после договоренности

В DWT необходимо сначала перевести изображение в градации серого, затем найти максимальное значение на гистограмме канала cH, а также сделать повторное вейвлет преобразование, обнулив коэффициенты с порогом значения в 70 и сравнить с изображениями

С использованием дескриптора SIFT сопоставить одно изображение с другим, найти координаты нулевой точки и интенсивности каналов B, G, R

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: C такими запросами на выполнение за вас домашнего задания (а не вопросами !) вам на форум к фрилансерам. Там вам с удовольствием "помогут".

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что so не фриланс сайт